# There's no way to know when state is updated when using dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux

In React, when I call setState, it has a callback to notify me the state has been setted. But when I use Redux, I use dispatch to change the state, but how can I know if the state has been updated.

For example:

```
dispatch({type: 'setCount', {count: 1}});

dispatch({type: 'add', {addedCount: this.state.count + 1}})
```

the second line depends on the first line, but we all know setState is not a synchronous operation, how can I handle this issue in Redux?

Comment: React components can still maintain a local state, which it seems like is what you want to do in this situation. if you have something that increments on click you can use a local state to maintain that. Dont need to over complicate a simple operation like that.

Comment: Well you can't. It's not a Redux problem. Redux is synchronous unless you use a store enhancer etc. However this is very interesting. I've never needed this even though I use a store enhancer for debouncing store updates. Could you give us a bit of more detail why you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the redux-thunk module you can return a Promise from your dispatched actions. dispatch(...) on these actions will magically return the Promises so you can .then(...) on them.

On the other hand, if your actions are synchronous, a setTimeout(..., 0) will do the trick.

Though in your example I think the second dispatch should be a simple setState as long as nothing external depends on it, in which case it shouldn't be local state at all but a composed action that does both of your actions at the same time. redux-thunk helps here too.

Comment: I can return a promise from my action function, but how can I know the state have been updated so that I can resolve the promise? in React ,setState has a callback to tell users the state has been changed. setTimeout really works, but I think it's not an official way.

Comment: The point is to reduce it to synchronous operations that you can setTimeout 0 to "wait" for. You do that by wrapping async stuff in Promises. setTimeout 0 is not a hack. It's a way to tell the interpreter to push some operation later in the execution stack, after everything else.

Comment: Yes, agree, but I still think it's not a good way. Anyway, thanks for your answer

Comment: There really is no "good way" then. Look into how react-redux stores the state, start from the Provider component. It probably does setState in there, maybe it exposes the callback somehow but it's not documented.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing a variable from the redux store to your component as a prop using mapStateToProps, you can do a **console.log(this.props.variableName) inside the render method of your component**. The render method will get called as soon as that variable is updated in the store.